# My USB mouse and keyboard is randomly disconnecting

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

Recently I've had in issue were my USB mouse and keyboard will stop working and I need to restart my computer from the power button to get them working again. Both my mouse and keyboard are Dragunov and wired. I have a computer that was built for me at a tech shop.

Comment: Sounds like bad use ports try them on another computer